# Are One-Step and OxyClean the same thing?

Tags: cleaning

They're both perchlorate-based cleaners.  I was thinking of buying some OxyClean when I ran out of One-Step and my LHBS only carried PBW and StarSan, but One-Step has worked so well for me that I don't want to risk it.

Are One Step and OxyClean interchangeable?

NOTE: Please spawn a new question to debate the merits of perchlorate as a sanitizer and cleanser.

Comment: I have no experience with Oxyclean, but just a heads up.  One-step is not a sanitizer.  Many people I know have been burned using as such.  The few online places I have looked at one-step in the past, state it as a cleanser.

Comment: Oxyclean is a sanitizer.  Sodium percarbonate becomes hydrogen peroxide and soda ash.  From Palmer's "How to Brew" for verification. http://www.howtobrew.com/section1/chapter2-2-1.html

Comment: Pardon, I meant One-Step is a sanitizer.  I don't think you should use Oxyclean as a sanitizer.

Comment: You can look up the MSDS for Oxyclean, One-Step and any other chemicals and find out just what's in them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would not use OxyClean as a sanitizer.

The people who make OxyClean are not required to tell you what is in OxyClean, beyond the sodium percarbonate.  There are likely UV brighteners and possibly other chemicals.  Because its not "food-safe" they don't have to put out a complete ingredient list.  I don't recommend you use it for a sanitizer because of that fact.

I use One-Step and have for years, mostly because I brew in the kitchen and most of the other cleaners could have a detrimental effect on the formica counter tops.  But One-Step, on a per-gallon basis is one of the most expensive sanitizers.  If you don't have those limitations, then Idophor or Starsan is much cheaper.